# azure webapp with c++ dll not working

Tags: c++, dll, azure-web-app-service

I've created a Azure Web in C# which references to a native C++ Dynamic library. On the local host application is running well.

But when I've deployed the web app to Cloud Azure, its not working. Not getting clue how to go forward. please help.

On the reset API call getting following "An error has occurred."

Comment: First you should check, if the dll and possible other dependencies can be found.

Comment: Also, check that dll bitness matches what your web app is configured to use (i.e. 32 vs 64 bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the reset API call getting following "An error has occurred."

To get the detail error information from ASP.NET REST API, we need to set the value of IncludeErrorDetailPolicy property as 'Always' in WebApiConfig.cs.

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

If the exception you got after changed the IncludeErrorDetailPolicy is **DllNotFoundException**, please make sure the native DLL is deployed successfully to Azure Web App bin folder. By default, the native DLL file will not be deployed with your VS publish. You need to upload this file to the bin folder of your web app using FTP or Kudu site.

If the exception you got after changed the IncludeErrorDetailPolicy is **BadImageFormatException**, you need to check the platform of your Web App and your native DLL.

[image]

If the platform of your Web App is 32 bit, please make sure the native DLL was build target Win32 or All Platforms. If you build the DLL on a 64 bit machine. All Platforms is required.

[image]

In addition, Azure Web App run in a secure environment called a sandbox. The sandbox generally aims to restrict access to shared components of Windows. For detail information, link below is for your reference.

[General Azure Web App Sandbox Restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions)

If your native DLL use one of the restricted APIs. Calling to your native DLL also will be failed. To see all the dependent modules of your native DLL, you could download and use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Thank you for responding. 
The error message i'm seeing is 
<ExceptionType>System.DllNotFoundException</ExceptionType>

This exception is thrown even though i've the correct dll in bin folder (/site/wwwroot/bin)

Comment: Which platform did you choose on your Web App? 32bit or 64bit? I also encounter the DllNotFoundException when I deploy my C++ DLL to a 32 bit Web App. Finally I resolved it by rebuilding the C++ DLL and choosing 'Win32' as Platform.

Comment: I've created web app for 64 bit platform and build the 64 bit C++ dll (release configuration).  This has resolved the issue. 
1. Generate C++ library using 64-bit configuration in relase mode.

Build-->configuration manager

Select ---> Reslease , Platform x64

2. Generate Web app using 64-bit configuration  Debug mode

Build-->configuration manager

Select ---> Debug , Platform x64

3. Run Web app in Azure in 64 bit configration.

Application settings --> 64 bit

Thank you @Amor-MSFT for providing the solution.